# Mapping array items to repeated list

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Here's an unsophisticated version of what I want to achieve:

```
$scope.colors = [{ "Name": "Red" },{ "Name": "Orange" },{ "Name": "Yellow" }];

<ul>
    <li>{{colors[0].Name}}</li>
    <li>{{colors[1].Name}}</li>
    <li>{{colors[2].Name}}</li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

But I'd like to do it more dynamically. That is, repeat 5 list items each containing an item from the array `colors` which may contain up to 5 items (in this case 3).

Comment: Fill your `colors` array so that it always has 5 items, some of them eventually empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it this way but you would get an extra span here..

```
   <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4,5]">
          <span ng-if="i<=colors.length">{{colors[i].name}}</span>
         </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: @Blackhole In that case there would be no <li> tag if there is not item...OP wants to have 5 <li> tags everytime

Answer (score 1):

In maandoo's answer, you will get an extra `<span>` element added between each `<li>`. Angular now supports ternary operators in expressions, so if you do not want the span to show up, you can simply the solution to:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="i in [0,1,2,3,4]">
    {{colors[i] ? colors[i].Name : ''}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

This also has the added benefit of removing 5 watchers from your code, because of the removal of 5 `ng-if` statements.